# migration of oracle xe 10 to xe 11 fails with wrong paths used in the import

Tags: oracle, migration, oracle-xe

I'm following [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm#XEINL175) to upgrade an OracleXE 10.2 database to OracleXE 11.2. The export succeeded without any problem, the import (on another machine with XE 11) fails though. The log file shows Oracle trying to put files in non-existant paths, and some paths still referring to XE 10:

```
;;; 
Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Vr Mrt 20 13:26:58 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
;;; 
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Master table "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
ORA-39060: table(s) dropped because of conflict with master table
Starting "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01":  system/<replaced asterisks for stackexchange formatting> full=Y directory=DUMP_DIR dumpfile=DB10G.dmp logfile=expdpDB10G1.log 
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/TABLESPACE
ORA-39083: Object type TABLESPACE failed to create with error:
ORA-01119: error in creating database file 'C:\OPT\ORACLEXE\ORADATA\XE\UNDO.DBF'
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 3) The system cannot find the path specified.
Failing sql is:
CREATE UNDO TABLESPACE "UNDO" DATAFILE 'C:\OPT\ORACLEXE\ORADATA\XE\UNDO.DBF' SIZE 52428800 AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 5242880 MAXSIZE 524288000 BLOCKSIZE 8192 EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE
ORA-31684: Object type TABLESPACE:"SYSAUX" already exists
ORA-31684: Object type TABLESPACE:"TEMP" already exists
ORA-31684: Object type TABLESPACE:"USERS" already exists
ORA-39083: Object type TABLESPACE failed to create with error:
ORA-01119: error in creating database file 'C:\OPT\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\SERVER\DATABASE\CRPTBL01.DBF'
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 3) The system cannot find the path specified.
```

My OracleXE 11 is installed like this (by specifying c:\opt in the install wizard):

```
c:\opt\oraclexe\app\oracle
c:\opt\oraclexe\app\oracle\admin
c:\opt\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag
c:\opt\oraclexe\app\oracle\fast_recovery_area
c:\opt\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata
c:\opt\oraclexe\app\oracle\product
```

So not only is the import tool trying to create files in a wrong dir:

```
ORA-01119: error in creating database file C:\OPT\ORACLEXE\ORADATA\XE\UNDO.DBF'
```

it is also refering to paths containing 10 versioning:

```
ORA-01119: error in creating database file 'C:\OPT\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\SERVER\DATABASE\CRPTBL01.DBF'
```

I have no idea where Oracle is getting these paths from?

Comment: I don't suppose just exporting or datapumping the schemas you are interested in rather than a full export will work?

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem is, in my XE 10 additional tablespaces were created. When the import into 11 discovers those tablespaces do not exist yet, it tries to recreate them with the statement with which they were created in the first place, in XE 10. That explains where the wrong paths are coming from. 
I just copy & pasted the create statements from the log, changed the paths, executed them, repeated the import and now it works.
A bit strange that the documentation doesn't mention this possible hiccup.